# Getting only 100 crawl issues using webmaster tool

Tags: google-search-console

I am using Feed crawlIssues = wtr.GetCrawlIssues(encodedSiteID); to get the crawl errors from my webmaster tool account. There are more than 5k errors but the above code retrieves just the first 100. How do I retrieve all the errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I've run into the same issue as you have, I only got the first 100 errors, too. Basically, because of a bug in the webmaster tools, it only shows you the errors in 100 batches. 
It does not have a built in solution as far as I know, but there is a workaround. Instead of using the GetCrawlIssues function, you can access the data through http requests with the provided ExecRequest.exe command line tool. The basic usage is:
ExecRequest cl QUERY http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/feeds/example_site.com/crawlissues/?start-index=1&max-results=100 example@gmail.com mypassword
This will output the resulting XML to the console. You can specify the starting point, and the number of errors you want to download: 
?start-index=startIndex
&max-results=100 
You can set the max-result value to wathever you want, but it will only download a maximum of 100 items.

After downloading in batches, you can get the data from the downloaded xml files.

If you only need the data, I've also written a small script in Python, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/fulibacsi/SmallProjects/tree/master/GData_Crawl_Error), it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Great first answer, keep up the good work!